# Spring Websocket Stomp handle CONNECT frame

Tags: spring, stomp, spring-websocket

is there any way to intercept STOMP `CONNECT` frame in Spring and refuse it under some conditions?
The interception itself can be done using `SessionConnectEvent` but I would like to allow or refuse the connection based on headers. I cannot do it in the `SessionConnectEvent` listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we take a look to the `StompSubProtocolHandler` code, we'll see this:

```
try {
    SimpAttributesContextHolder.setAttributesFromMessage(message);
    if (this.eventPublisher != null) {
        if (StompCommand.CONNECT.equals(headerAccessor.getCommand())) {
            publishEvent(new SessionConnectEvent(this, message, user));
        }
........
    outputChannel.send(message);
}
```

So, the `CONNECT` frame not only emitted as a `SessionConnectEvent`, but is sent to the `clientInboundChannel` as well.

So, what you need to achieve you requirement is just providing a custom `ChannelInterceptor` with `preSend` implementation and register it overriding `WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer.configureClientInboundChannel`.

Comment: I have tried the `ChannelInterceptor` before but it looked like the `CONNECT` frame was not intercepted... Probably I have done something wrong. I tried again after reading your answer and it worked. Thank you. The only reason why I do not like the `ChannelInterceptor` is that it is invoked on every frame while I need intercept only the `CONNECT` frame. Anyway, the solution meets my requirement.